# $nCr$ for unique order of selection

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

> in how many ways can $r$ object be selected from $n$ object if the order of selection is also to be considered

By the principle of counting we know, there are $n$ ways to select the first object and $(n-r+1)$ to select the $r^{th}$ object. This gives us the famous $nCr$.

The drawback of $nCr$ being there is no uniqueness of selection of order, I wanted to know in how many ways can we select $r$ from $n$ object where the order of selection matters.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135081/discussion-on-question-by-abhisek-ganguly-ncr-for-unique-order-of-selection).

Answer (score 1):

The question was clarified in the comment section, this answer is summary.

To maintain the relevance of the order, multiply it with the factorial of the number of objects you're selecting(which is $r$ is my case), rather than the number you're selecting it from($n$).

> $nCr \times r!$